# How to add two tuples in a list

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tuples

I need to find an average of these numbers extracted from a database table. I managed to extract the numbers and they are fetched as two tuples in a list. How can I get to add them and get an average?

This is my code

```
def getAllShirts():
   conn = sqlite3.connect('MainDatabase.db')
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute('SELECT Senti_result FROM Comments_table WHERE pid = 2')
   return cur.fetchall()

print(getAllShirts())
```

This is the format of numbers I extracted `[(0.6000000000000001,), (0.35,)]`
I expect my output to be `0.47500000000000003` which is the average of two numbers

Comment: `0.80000000005` is the sum of the values, and not the average

Comment: Why not compute the average in the query? `SELECT avg(senti_result) FROM ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tuples_avg = sum([i[0] for i in tuples])/len(tuples)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop through the tuple, sum all elements and then calculate the average

```
tuples = [(0.6000000000000001,), (0.35,)]

sum = 0
for tpl in tuples:
    sum += tpl[0]

avg = sum/len(tuples)
print(avg)
#0.47500000000000003
```

Comment: Done, Thank you so much!

Comment: Sir, why are we using `tpl[0]` ?

Comment: Because we always refer to element of tuples by indexes, the tuple here is of length 1, and the first element is referenced by `tpl[0]`

Comment: Also I saw you accepted then unaccepted my answer, was something you didn't understand?

Comment: No sir, I apologize, Your answer is absolutely correct, just that another user posted a more optimized solution

Comment: Sure, the other answer uses list comprehension, which I feel is sometimes too advanced for a new user.

Comment: Thank You for your time, Sir :)